# phoenix framework deployment issue

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, conform, exrm

I am trying to deploy a Phoenix app using exrm and conform. Testing the release on local Ubuntu works. But when i run the same on server there is failure. I am not able to understand the exact cause.

{error_logger,{{2016,1,30},{7,45,44}},"Protocol: ~tp: register/listen error: ~tp~n",["inet_tcp",etimedout]}
{error_logger,{{2016,1,30},{7,45,44}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{net_kernel,init,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.22.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{error,badarg},[{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,344}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]}},{ancestors,[net_sup,kernel_sup,<0.10.0>]},{messages,[]},{links,[#Port<0.380>,<0.19.0>]},{dictionary,[{longnames,true}]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,987},{stack_size,27},{reductions,842}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2016,1,30},{7,45,44}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,net_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{'EXIT',nodistribution}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{id,net_kernel},{mfargs,{net_kernel,start_link,[['app@127.0.0.1',longnames]]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,worker}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2016,1,30},{7,45,44}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{id,net_sup},{mfargs,{erl_distribution,start_link,[]}},{restart_type,permanent},{shutdown,infinity},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2016,1,30},{7,45,44}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3','Argument__4']}},{pid,<0.9.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}},[{application_master,init,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,134}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]}},{ancestors,[<0.8.0>]},{messages,[{'EXIT',<0.10.0>,normal}]},{links,[<0.8.0>,<0.7.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,376},{stack_size,27},{reductions,117}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2016,1,30},{7,45,44}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}},{k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error reason is usually at the first line of error and crashdump:

```
{error_logger,{{2016,1,30},{7,45,44}},"Protocol: ~tp: register/listen error: ~tp~n",["inet_tcp",etimedout]}...

({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_sup,{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}}}}...
```

During startup there was error while opening listen socket with timeout `etimedout`. This may be caused by couple of things:

- your application is already running and you can't open the same port twice,
- there are firewall restrictions - check iptables especially for port 4369 (Erlang port mapper daemon)
- your app doesn't have privileges to open that port

`iex` starts your app with `dev` environment, while `exrm` uses `prod`.
Compare your `dev` and `prod` settings. Probably there are different ports defined. Try running your app with `iex`, but with `prod` environment.

```
MIX_ENV=prod iex -S mix phoenix.server
```

Remember that generated release has all the config values evaluated during creation and hardcoded.

Comment: iptables issue. I had added the port but did not restart iptables

Comment: Great thorough answer @tkowal!  Kudos!